# WIF ChannelActingAs access claims from WCF

Tags: wcf, wif, claims-based-identity

I want to access custom claims added to the current principal in the UI layer from a WCF service.
I have a web application that add claims to CurrentPrincipal once the user has been authenticated by the STS. This works fine.

```
    protected void WSFederationAuthenticationModule_SecurityTokenValidated(object sender, SecurityTokenValidatedEventArgs args)
    {
        var customPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(args.ClaimsPrincipal);
        var service = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IServices>();

        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = customPrincipal;
        var result = service.GetPemissions();

        foreach (var claim in result.Claims)
            customPrincipal.Identities.First().Claims.Add(new Claim(claim.ClaimType, claim.Value));                      

        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = customPrincipal;
        args.ClaimsPrincipal = customPrincipal;
    }
```

At some point I would like to make a request to a WCF Service and have the claims passed over to the service. If I use the CreateChannelActingAS passing in the bootstrap token I don't get the claims that were added to the principal from the previous step.

```
var claimsPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as IClaimsPrincipal;
var securityToken = claimsPrincipal.Identities.First().BootstrapToken;
using (var channel = channelFactory.Value.CreateChannelActingAs(securityToken) as IClientChannel)
{
try
  {
      invocation.ReturnValue = invocation.Method.Invoke(channel, invocation.Arguments);
  { ...
```

Is there any way to construct a ClaimsPrincipal in the WCF Service and have the additional claims come across that were added in the UI layer? Can I create a new securityToken and pass that through the channel or is there a better way of approaching this in general?

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstraptoken is literally the token which the WIF Identity was originally created from and thus it will not contain any claims added or transformed after the initial creation. The way WIF works (with secure tokens) means effectively that the calling clients should never be able to manipulate the token contents in any way (or at least the receiver should not be able to validate such malicious tokens).

Depending on the chosen IDM architecture, there are some options on how to proceed. Simplest option is to make another call to the STS and specify the required additional claims in a RequestSecurityToken request. It is however in the consideration of STS to either accept or deny the incoming claims and there are multitude of options for handling this in custom STS code. If there is no control over the STS (and no intermediate repeater can be set up), then the hard way could be to use additional WCF security such as supporting tokens. These require manual configuration and operations if they are to be delegated further along the WCF road.

Note of warning though, the identity management model is essentially a collection of trust relationships and by allowing a STS client to specify site-wide (or where-ever the token is distributed/federated/etc) valid claims is rather shady design. After all, since the claims would now come from the WCF callers, one could just simply pass them as parameters in the WCF method calls anyways with the exactly same level of security. The only benefit from adding them to the WIF identity tokens (properly) would be that they would be automatically delegated/shared in ActAs/OnBehalfOf situations.